# android.support.customtabs.extra.KEEP_ALIVE

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

What is the public API to pass on service name for custom tabs? Sample app uses the following and works as expected but i don't see it in official documentation. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.html)

```
private static final String EXTRA_CUSTOM_TABS_KEEP_ALIVE =
            "android.support.customtabs.extra.KEEP_ALIVE";

Intent keepAliveIntent = new Intent().setClassName(
                context.getPackageName(), KeepAliveService.class.getCanonicalName());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CUSTOM_TABS_KEEP_ALIVE, keepAliveIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no public api for setting keep alive as for now. You can check it by yourself from the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/c502e63/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.java) of `CustomTabsIntent.Builder`.